# Why cannot a kernel be launched with the reason of too many register use when there is a register spilling mechanism?

Tags: memory-management, cuda

1) When does a kernel start to spill registers to local memory?

2) When there is not enough registers, how does the CUDA runtime decide to not launch a kernel and throws too many resources requested error? How many registers are enough to launch a kernel?

3) Since there is a register spilling mechanism, shouldn't all CUDA kernels be launched even if there are not enough registers?

Comment: 1 and (2 and 3) are completely unrelated. Register spilling is a static operation performed by the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) When does a kernel start to spill registers to local memory?

This is entirely under control of the compiler.  It is not performed by the runtime, and there are no dynamic runtime decisions about it.  When your code reaches the point of a spill, it means that the compiler has inserted an instruction like:

```
STL  [R0], R1
```

In this case, `R1` is being stored to local memory, the local memory address given in `R0`.  This would be  a spill store.  (After that instruction, `R1` could be used for/loaded with something else.)  The compiler knows when it has done this, of course, and so it can report the number of spill loads and spill stores it has chosen to use/make.  You can get this information (along with register usage, and other information) using the `-Xptxas=-v` compiler switch.

The compiler (unless you restrict it, see below) makes decisions about register usage primarily focused on performance, paying otherwise less attention to how many registers are actually used.  The first priority is performance.

> 2) When there is not enough registers, how does the CUDA runtime decide to not launch a kernel and throws too many resources requested error? How many registers are enough to launch a kernel?

At compile-time, when your kernel code is being compiled, the compiler has no idea how it will be launched.  It has no idea what your launch configuration will be like (number of blocks, number of threads per block, amount of dynamically allocated shared memory, etc)  In fact the compilation process mostly proceeds as if the thing being compiled is a single thread.

During compilation, the compiler makes a bunch of static decisions about register assignments (how and where registers will be used).  CUDA has [binary utilities](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html) that can help with understanding this.  Register assignments don't change at runtime, are not in any way dynamic, and therefore are entirely determined at compile time.  Therefore, at the completion of compilation for a given device code function, it is generally possible to determine how many registers are needed.  The compiler includes this information in the binary compiled object.

At runtime, at the point of kernel launch, the CUDA runtime now knows:

- How many registers (per thread) are needed for a given kernel
- What device we are running on, and therefore what the aggregate limits are
- What the launch configuration is (blocks, threads)

Assembling these 3 pieces of information means the runtime can immediately know if there is or will be enough "register space" for the launch.  Roughly speaking, the pass/fail arithmetic is if the launch would satisfy this inequality:

```
 registers_per_thread*threads_per_block <= max_registers_per_multiprocessor
```

There is granularity to be considered in this equation as well. Registers are often allocated in groups of 2 or 4 at runtime, i.e. the `registers_per_thread` quantity may need to be rounded up to the next whole-number multiple of something like 2 or 4, before the inequality test is applied.  The `registers_per_thread` quantity is ascertained by the compiler as already described.  The `threads_per_block` quantity comes from your kernel launch configuration.  The `max_registers_per_multiprocessor` quantity is machine-readable (i.e. it is a function of the GPU you are running on).  You can see how to retrieve that quantity yourself if you wish by studying the `deviceQuery` CUDA sample code.

> 3) Since there is a register spilling mechanism, shouldn't all CUDA kernels be launched even if there are not enough registers?

I reiterate that the register assignment (and register spill decisions) is/are entirely a static compile-time process.  No runtime decisions or alterations are made.  The register assignment is entirely inspectable from the compiled code.  Therefore, since no adjustments can be made at runtime, no changes could be made to allow an arbitrary launch.  Any such change would require recompilation of the code.  While this might be theoretically possible, it is not currently implemented in CUDA.  Furthermore, it has the possibility to lead to both variable and perhaps unpredictable behavior (in performance) so there might be reasons not to do it.

Its possible to make all kernels "launchable" (with respect to register limitations) by suitably restricting the compiler's choices about register assignment.  [`__launch_bounds__`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#launch-bounds) and the [compiler switch](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-steering-gpu-code-generation-maxrregcount) `-maxrregcount` are a couple ways to achieve this.  CUDA provides both an [occupancy calculator](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-occupancy-calculator/index.html) as well as an [occupancy API](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#occupancy-calculator) to help with this process.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. Exactly the answers I was looking for.